# foreverコマンド

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

discordのbot作成でつまづきました。node.jsで作成し、foreverコマンドで動かしているのですが、リプライを何件も送るバグ(?)みたいなのがおきています。これはforeverコマンドの実行のたびに増えていきます。

```
//ログイン処理
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'とーくん';
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready...');
});
//Bot自身の発言を無視する呪い
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(message.author.bot){
        return;
    }
//↓ここに後述のコードをコピペする↓
    if (message.content === '寒いね') {
        let channel = message.channel;
        let author = message.author.username;
        let reply_text =`寒いね`;
        message.reply(reply_text)
            .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${reply_text}`))
            .catch(console.error);
        return;
    }
    if (message.content === '暑いね') {
        let channel = message.channel;
        let author = message.author.username;
        let reply_text =`暑いね`;
        message.reply(reply_text)
            .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${reply_text}`))
            .catch(console.error);
        return;
    }
    if (message.content.match(/おはよ/)) {
        message.channel.send(`${author}さん、おはようございます！`)
    }
    if (message.content.match(/discord.gg/)) {
        message.delete(100)
    }
//↑ここに後述のコードをコピペする↑
});
client.login(token);
```

おはよの部分は一回だけなのですが"寒いね"の部分が何回も繰り返されます。どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: foreverコマンドのたびに増えるということなので、とりあえずbotが複数同時に動いていないか確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。`forever list`で現在foreverによって動いているスクリプトが一覧表示されます。

Comment: 見てみましたが、自分で作ったtwitterのbot以外動いてないですね･･･そもそもdiscordのbotの反映が遅いということは無いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

node discord.jsで起動しましょう！

確実に動くと思います。